# Easy way to visualize DOCX XMls

Tags: xml, ms-word, zip, docx

I generally see the MS word docx file via unzipping it and manually opening each XML file in some browser or notepad.

Is there any DOCX document viewer available which could be used to visualize the nodes in each XML with just a click? Something like dragging and dropping a document to it and all XML would be visible and we can traverse through content of all of these without the need of web browser or notepad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something what very likely fits your description is Productivity Tool from  [Open XML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425)

Comment: Nice, super-set of what I was looking for.